# find nearest number index + match +min + abs with multiple match criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula

How can I find the nearest number? Match with two criteria (name and date).

```
=INDEX(G6:G18,MATCH(1,MIN((K3=E6:E18)*(L3=F6:F18),ABS(G6:G18-M3)),ABS(G6:G18-M3),0))
```

***Excel data for nearest number:***

[image]

Comment: How result coming 94?

Comment: What version of Excel?  Do you have Dynamic Arrays?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I 'll combine the conditions together, the **nearest value** will have **1/(difference)** the greatest, at this time the aggregate will work, then just find its index by using match, here is the formula:

```
=INDEX(M3:M8,MATCH(AGGREGATE(14,6,1/((K3:K8=O2)*(L3:L8=P2)*(ABS(Q2-M3:M8)+1)),1),1/((K3:K8=O2)*(L3:L8=P2)*(ABS(Q2-M3:M8)+1)),0))
```

[image]

**Update:** Thanks @Ron Rosenfeld for the feedback! The previous formula did not work when difference=0.

Hope it works!

Comment: I think problem with your algorhythm when **difference = 0**. Try:  `O2: CC`; `P2: 1/3/2019`; `Q2: 23`  Expected `23`; your Result: `15`

Comment: Hi,I have updated the formula. I checked, it seems to work!

Answer (score 0):

You don't indicate what you want if Number is equidistant from both numbers in the table. Depending on the order, these formulas might return one or the other.

Note that I converted your data into a Table, and am using structured references.  But these formulas will work equally well with regular addressing.

If you have the latest version of Excel with the `FILTER` function:

```
=INDEX(INDEX(FILTER(Table1,(K3=Table1[Name])*(L3=Table1[date])),0,3),MATCH(MIN(ABS(M3-INDEX(FILTER(Table1,(K3=Table1[Name])*(L3=Table1[date])),0,3))),ABS(M3-INDEX(FILTER(Table1,(K3=Table1[Name])*(L3=Table1[date])),0,3)),0))
```

If you do not have the `FILTER` function, try:

```
=INDEX(AGGREGATE(15,6,1/((K3=Table1[Name])*(L3=Table1[date]))*Table1[number],ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&COUNT(1/((K3=Table1[Name])*(L3=Table1[date])))))),MATCH(MIN(ABS(M3-AGGREGATE(15,6,1/((K3=Table1[Name])*(L3=Table1[date]))*Table1[number],ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&COUNT(1/((K3=Table1[Name])*(L3=Table1[date])))))))),ABS(M3-AGGREGATE(15,6,1/((K3=Table1[Name])*(L3=Table1[date]))*Table1[number],ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&COUNT(1/((K3=Table1[Name])*(L3=Table1[date]))))))),0))
```

[image]